# mfc c++ calculation resulting in a after 9 then back to 1

Tags: c++, mfc, numbers

to get my head around calculation in c++ i started basic and came up with this code.

```
m_cont.GetWindowText(m_value);
int a;
a = _wtoi(m_value) + 1;
TCHAR buff[50];
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(_itot(a, buff, 50));
```

it adds 1 to whatever number is in the edit control on a click of a button which works, but it goes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, 1, and repeat. i know it's a very basic calculation here, but how come it doesn't hit 10 and continue adding 1 forever?

Comment: Why don't you step through the code in the debugger and see?

Comment: i have tried, but the debugger doesn't output anything when i try to use buttons. only on open and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of [`_itot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt.aspx) (which is a variant of the non-standard `itoa` function) is not the length of the buffer, but the base to do the conversion as. So your code is doing conversion in base 50, in which the digit 'a' follows 9. You should specify the base as 10.